# WP7: How to downscale an image smoothly?

Tags: image, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm developing a Windows Phone app (for technical reasons it must be WP7). I need to show images that are originally stored as hi-res PNGs, but they are shown at a smaller size. I'm using an `<Image>` inside a `<Grid>` with star row heights.

The problem is that the downscaled images look kind of choppy (as if the downscaling algorithm is not good), but I can't seem to find a way to show them smoothly without knowing beforehand the display size of the image and generating a new image programmatically.

Is there a property that I can change so that the app uses a different downscaling algorithm and so the image is only defined in XAML, or am I stuck with having to write logic in the code behind so that the image looks smooth?

Update: I got some screenshots to show the problem.

1. Just an `<Image>` inside a `<Grid>`

[image: Choppy logo]

2. An `<Image>` inside a `<ViewBox>` inside a `<Grid>`

[image: Choppy logo with ViewBox]

ViewBox can help with scaling, but the algorithm it uses is the same, which is not useful at all to me.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox)

Comment: As there is a limited number of resolutions you will have to deal with, could download the image at the required size from a server, where it has been prepared with a better resampling algorithm?

Comment: I could preprocess them on the server, but I'm kind of curious too if this can be done purely with XAML syntax. If it can't, then I will use your solution.

Comment: Embed them in a ViewBox with whatever sizes you require and you won't have to worry about the rest. That's what it's specifically made to do.

Comment: OK, I will try using ViewBox, but I will leave the question open while I try.

Comment: I already tried it. It looks exactly the same as before (i.e. choppy). I will add some pictures to the question.

Answer (score 0):

See below post to re-size image this might help you

The Microsoft.Phone assembly includes `WriteableBitmap class, SaveJpeg()`. The SaveJpeg signature looks like this:
You can specify image height and width for scaling.

```
public static void SaveJpeg(
  this WriteableBitmap bitmap, 
  Stream targetStream, 
  int targetWidth, 
  int targetHeight, 
  int orientation, 
  int quality 
  );
```

[Resizing Images in Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/resizing-images-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)